# What is Shaktadvaita tradition?

Tags: shakti, shaktism, reference-request

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi-Bhagavata_Purana) from Wikipedia says Devi Bhagavata Purana "promotes bhakti (devotion) towards Mahadevi, integrating themes from the **Shaktadvaitavada tradition** (syncretism of Samkhya and Advaita Vedanta. literally, the path of nondualistic Shakti)". I never heard of this term. Is it an authentic theological term in Hinduism? Or Wikipedia just invented it? Please explain this term with authentic reference.

Comment: I think the use of the words synthesis or 'syncretism' with regard to the Samkaya school and the Advaita school is misleading. No doubt, there are many minor schools that blend traditions, but the Samkhya school is not really classified as a 'dualistic' school. Many Advaitists can be tantric followers of Shakti - Adi Shankaracharya was a devoted worshiper of Shakti, but no one would call him a blender of the Samkhya and Advaita schools. The Samkhya School is a completely separate school from the Uttara Mimamsa schools which include both the modern dualists and non-dualists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly wasn't *invented* by Wikipedia, since I can find some earlier scholarly references to it. However, the term isn't referred to in any primary Hindu scripture.

Swami Prajnanananda writes in *[Schools of Indian Thought](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Schools_of_Indian_Philosophical_Thought/_hsgAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Shaktadvaitavada&dq=Shaktadvaitavada&printsec=frontcover)*

> If we look at the dualism on the *sadhana* side, we may be tempted to call it dualistic or pluralistic just as we please. In fact, Tantra philosophy upholds out-and-out the *shaktadvaitavada,* which means a synthesis of the dualistic and monoistic systems of thought.

Much earlier, indologist Arthur Avalon wrote a chapter in his famous *Shakti and Shâkta* which was titled '[Shakta Advaitavada](https://www.sacred-texts.com/tantra/sas/sas18.htm).' There are a handful of other references to this in the book, which mainly tell us that according to Shakta Advaitavada,

- man is both Consciousness and Unconsciousness, or both *Chita* and *Achita*
- mulaprakriti, or fundamental matter, is genuine, and involves Maya-Shakti
- consciousness is essential to discovering Shakti
- spirit and matter are neither fully distinct nor fully the same; they are two sides to one coin

So Wikipedia is not incorrect, as Shaktadvaitavada is a Shaktic tradition which blends the dualistic (samkhya) with the monoistic (Advaita Vedanta).

Comment: how a man can be both conscious and unconscious? sounds bizarre.

Comment: I think the use of the words synthesis or 'syncretism' with regard to the Samkaya school and the Advaita school is misleading. No doubt, there are many minor schools that blend traditions, but the Samkhya school is not really classified as a 'dualistic' school. Many Advaitists can be tantric followers of Shakti - Adi Shankaracharya was a devoted worshiper of Shakti, but no one would call him a blender of the Samkhya and Advaita schools. The Samkhya School is a completely separate school from the Uttara Mimamsa schools which include both the modern dualists and non-dualists.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay - It's certainly a bit of a strange concept to grasp. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAXAo.png) a screenshot of that part of the book if you want to read the full analysis.